# BehaviorSpace having trouble to deal with subexperiments?

Tags: netlogo, behaviorspace

I am trying to run various subexperiments in NetLogo using BehaviorSpace as indicated [in the BehaviorSpace Guide](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/behaviorspace.html#subexperiment-syntax).

When defining the experiment, I am writing variables to vary as in the chunk below:

```
["general-value" TRUE]
[["subvariable_1_1" 2] ["subvariable_1_2" 5] ["subvariable_2_1" "none"] ["subvariable_2_2" "none"]]
[["subvariable_1_1" 2] ["subvariable_1_2" 5] ["subvariable_2_1" 8] ["subvariable_2_2" 14]]
```

When trying to save the experiments settings through the "ok" button in the experiment window, I get an error message with the following error:

> The following values are invalid: variable: unexpected error with provided list

I've tried several modifications, such as removing the "general-value" variable, removing blank spaces between brackets, revising the syntax... But it seems like the error caused by having a list of lists `[[...][...]]`, although the guide clearly states this is the way to run several experiments.

Has anyone found themselves in a similar situation?

By the way, I want to use this configuration as there are some limitations regarding the subvariables. When they are numeric, it is necessary that `subvariable_1_1 < subvariable_1_2` and `subvariable_2_1 < subvariable_2_2`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You most certainly don't use NetLogo Version 6.4. The distinct experiment setting you want to use was only made available in the most recent NetLogo release 6.4.0. I could reproduce your error with an older NetLogo version but with 6.4.0. your example works fine.

Comment: You were completely right, I hadn't updated to NetLogo 6.4 and was still using 6.3. I noticed an evident change in the BehaviorSpace window when tried 6.4 and that gave me no problem at all. Thanks for your help, I didn't think of checking if I was using the latest version.